# ngx-owl-carousle-o pagination not working in Angular 10

Tags: pagination, runtime-error, carousel, angular10

I've simple application with Angular 10 and I'm using ngx-owl-carousel in it. I've problem with pagination. When I try to click next page it does not work as expected and this error appear.

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'translate3d(-297px,0px,0px)'. Current value: 'translate3d(-1488px,0px,0px)'.
    at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.js:5625)
    at bindingUpdated (core.js:13962)
    at bindingUpdated2 (core.js:13977)
    at bindingUpdated4 (core.js:13986)
    at Module.ɵɵpureFunction5 (core.js:24421)
    at StageComponent_Template (ngx-owl-carousel-o.js:3393)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7449)
    at refreshView (core.js:7318)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8465)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7126)
```

carousel.component.html

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h3 *ngIf="data.products.length !== 0" class="category-title">{{data.title}}</h3>

    <owl-carousel-o (dragging)="isDragging = $event.dragging" [options]="customOptions">

        <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of data.products">
            <ng-template carouselSlide>
                <a *ngIf="slide.product_type == 1 || slide.product_type == 4" [owlRouterLink]="['/animations', slide.id]" [stopLink]="isDragging"  class="image">
                    <img [src]="slide.feature_avatar.xxxdpi" [alt]="" [title]="slide.name">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h4>{{slide.name}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a *ngIf="slide.product_type == 3" [owlRouterLink]="['/animations/collection', slide.id]" [stopLink]="isDragging"  class="image">
                    <img [src]="slide.feature_avatar.xxxdpi" [alt]="" [title]="slide.name">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h4>{{slide.name}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </ng-template>
        </ng-container>

    </owl-carousel-o>

</div>
```

carousel.componen.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeItem, Result } from 'src/app/shared/models/homeMain.model';
import { OwlOptions } from 'ngx-owl-carousel-o';

@Component({
  selector: 'carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.scss']
})
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {
  customOptions: OwlOptions;
  isDragging: boolean;
  constructor() { }

  @Input() data: Result

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customOptions = {
      rtl: false,
      loop: true,
      lazyLoad: true,
      mouseDrag: true,
      touchDrag: true,
      pullDrag: false,
      dots: true,
      navSpeed: 700,
      navText: ['', ''],
      margin: 10,
      stagePadding: 10,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 2
        },
        400: {
          items: 3
        },
        740: {
          items: 3
        },
        940: {
          items: 5
        },
        1024: {
          items: 5
        }
      },
      nav: false
    }
  }
}
```

it's work with angular 8 but it doesn't in angular 10 and I have another problem this routing not working  and it's not clickable even.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `*ngIf` directive is a tag in sliders. Put the `*ngIf` directive like this into `<ng-template carouselSlide>`

```
<owl-carousel-o (dragging)="isDragging = $event.dragging" [options]="customOptions">
    <ng-template carouselSlide *ngIf="slide.product_type == 1 || slide.product_type == 4">
        <a [owlRouterLink]="['/animations', slide.id]" [stopLink]="isDragging" class="image">
            <img [src]="slide.feature_avatar.xxxdpi" [alt]="" [title]="slide.name">
            <div class="title">
                <h4>{{slide.name}}</h4>
            </div>
        </a>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template carouselSlide *ngIf="slide.product_type == 3">
        <a [owlRouterLink]="['/animations/collection', slide.id]" [stopLink]="isDragging" class="image">
            <img [src]="slide.feature_avatar.xxxdpi" [alt]="" [title]="slide.name">
            <div class="title">
                <h4>{{slide.name}}</h4>
            </div>
        </a>
    </ng-template>
</owl-carousel-o>
```